# SOAP action using savon version 2 ruby gem

Tags: ruby, xml, soap, savon

I am working on a client for a SOAP service, I got the authentication XML HTTP post with wireshark, how do I create the same post using savon 2 ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something along these lines

```
...
client = Savon::Client.new "https://...?wsdl"
response = client.request "VerifyUserAccount" do  
  soap.input = ["VerifyUserAccount", {"xmlns" => "http://tempuri.org/uri_api_2008/service/"}]
  soap.body = {
    "Arguments" => ["Admin",1234]
    ...
  }
  ...
end  
...
```

Comment: It looks like your answer is for savon v.1 , I'm using savon v.2, I'll try to figure out the changes I need to do, thank you.

Comment: No, sorry this dose not produce the needed XML response .